# Null reference exception in page load aftre initialising variable

Tags: asp.net, nullreferenceexception, pageload

I have searched all over the net for a solution and it seems like a really simple question but I am getting a null reference exception whenever i try to save a variable to the session variable.  Below is my code.  When i get to the **SaveTreeView** method i get the null reference exception.  The quickwatch debugger shows the correct values.  I have tried assigning an arbitrary object to the list and this doesnt work either.  Any ideas?

```
    private TreeViewState state;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name);

        if (roles.Count() != 0)
        {
            var service = new TreeMapService();

            List<TreeStructure> treeMap = new List<TreeStructure>();

            //treeMap = service.GetTreeMap(roles[0]);
            //int me = treeMap.First().ChildNode.ID;

            state.SaveTreeView(treeMap);

            AddChildren(null, TreePanelMain, null, state.GetTreeView());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your problem is with the state variable my man.

Answer (score 2):

`state` is not initialized anyhow, so as a class member it is null be default. You need something like this:

```
state = new TreeViewState();
state.SaveTreeView(treeMap);
```